# queryPurchaseHistoryAsync state of subscription

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

I am trying to implement In App purchases Subscriptions.
Google documentation says

> queryPurchases method returns results from cache &
>   queryPurchaseHistoryAsync returns results from server & 
>    returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each product ID, even if that purchase is expired, cancelled, or consumed.

In my app, i wanted to check if user has already subscribed to a particular result so i can enable or disable the feature accordingly. 
The problem with queryPurchaseHistoryAsync is that its not giving status of the Purchases if its expired, cancelled or consume. Since, this method if getting data from server directly ,

*is there any way i can find the status of the subscription from it that if it is active or expired* ?

OR

is there any better way for my scenario to get subscribed subscriptions that haven't expired yet ?(apart from GOOGLE API for which i need server)

Comment: Google documentation states that : " You can then call a variety of methods on the Purchase object to view relevant information about the item, such as its purchase state or time, " But i couldn't find any property in Purchase object that can tell me the state of subscription

Comment: related issue without resolution: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/122